# How to update a datagris seamlessly for a dashboard associated to a dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset, dashboard

I have a datagrid depicting information for a dashboard on two columns. The number of lines instead is chosen by the user prior launch.
Data can be updated up to once per second on the runtime.

[image]

The problem is that the datagrid is "formed" on the runtime by changing the associated dataset and that causes some flickering.

The 1st implementation was

```
dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();<----- flickers 
foreach (...required keyword...)
{
    ...
    dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Add(label, value);<----flickers
    ...
}
dtgWatch.ItemsSource = dtsWatch.Tables[0].DefaultView;<----flickers
```

So the second implementation was based on the idea of "detaching" the datagrid from the dataset and working on a temporary dataset

```
dtvTemp = (DataView)dtgWatch.ItemsSource;<---temporary dataset clone from datagrid
dtgWatch.ItemsSource = dtvTemp;<-------------datagrid associate to temporary dataset
dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();<------------unassociated datagrid reset
foreach (...required keyword...)
{
    ...
    dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Add(label, value);<---unassociated datagrid rows add
    ...
}
dtgWatch.ItemsSource = dtsWatch.Tables[0].DefaultView;<----reassociation to primary datagrid
```

All this because in WPF I couldn't find any command to "freeze" the datagrid when updating the dataset. And in any case also the second approach doesn't reduces the flickering at all!
Is there another, better approach when it comes to updating a datagrid?

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Comment: What doesn't "work at all"? You should be able to set the `ItemsSource` to whatever `IEnumerable` you want, whenever you want.

Comment: Sorry I updated the sentence

Comment: Tried datatable's Begin/End Load Data methods?